# document.getElementById() returning null on input element

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and trying to select an element by id. It works well with a div element, but for some weird reason it keep returning null when I try to select an input element with an id.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Below is my code. Thanks!

```
<input type='hidden' id='hi'>


<script>

    console.log(document.getElementById("hi"));

</script>
```

#### Edit: added runnable snippet

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("hi"));
```

```html
<input type='hidden' id='hi'>
```

Comment: Seems to work ok.  See here:  https://jsfiddle.net/30gepsu2/

Comment: This issue, based on the posted code, would be impossible for anyone else in the entire world to reproduce, as the example posted works, everywhere.

Comment: You can post runnable snippets here. And when you do that, it works just fine. So this will be closed as "not able to replicate" pretty soon… ;-)

Comment: It will work. Your runnable snippet works too. Only thing is, you should check it in the console of your browser. I think that is what you are missing.

Comment: Your code snippet runs fine.  I think Thomas Sebastian is right....you need to open your console window to see the output.  Try pressing F12 to open the console window.

Comment: Most likely in your actual code you are calling `getElementByid` before the input element is in the DOM.

Comment: you input element contains blank as a value therefore you receive null

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I am refreshed my browser  and the code was correct.